# Nook store

Tags: android

Сегодня перевели на меня очень давно лежащий тикет, смысл которого очень туманен для меня.

> Nook Tablet: Power button
> functionality is not correctly
> supported by your app. Pressing the
> power button exits the app to the wake
> screen., instead of turning off

Nook Tablet-а у меня нет, а на других девайсах я не фиксирую ошибку. Кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобным?

В общем само по себе приложение это игрушка написанная на AndEngine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем-то надо сказать руководству, все что думаешь по данному поводу и попросить все что нужно, а иначе останешься крайним, был уже такой опыт, когда нужного девайса нет.

Comment: я имел опыт устранения багов, которые присылают с B&N (nook) и Kindle (Amazon). Их логику не всегда можно понять.

Но девайс себе лучше выпросить. Кстати, с нуком там ещё нужно будет пройти квест, что бы можно было туда заливать свои программы - получить от B&N специальный ключ.